# Python Selenium CHROMEDRIVER

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

So I'm currently using chromedriver for selenium with Python, responses are quite slow, so I'm trying to reduce how much chromedriver loads..

is there anyway I can remove the address bar, tool bar and most of the gui from chrome its self using chrome arguments?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think hiding the address bar and other GUI elements will have any effect. I would like to suggest using PhantomJS, a headless browser without a GUI at all. This will certainly speed up your tests.